# Cumulative sum in excel with certain criteria

Tags: excel

I have typed out an equation that I have dragged it down in a column in my excel table. I think I’m fairly close… and would love some feedback around this.

I want cumulative sum of the first cell `$J$3` to the cell row it’s currently on (`J53` for example). And I want cumulative sum of the particular cells that meet these conditions (ie… `COUNTIF($B$3:B53,B53)*COUNTIF(AC53,1)`.

I know the `Sumif()` statement below isn’t correct… but this was as close as I could get!

```
=IF((COUNTIF($B$3:B53,B53)*COUNTIF(AC53,1)),(SUMIF($J$3:J53,J53)),0)
```

As shown in the table below

| Projectid(B) | successornot(AC) | production(J) | result I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 20 |
| 1 | 1 | 40 | 60 |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 70 |
| 2 | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 400 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 20 | 20 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 24 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 50 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 7 | 1 | 40 | 50 |
| 7 | 1 | 20 | 70 |

Comment: Why result id `40` for 2nd `7`. It should be `50` as `10+40=50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on

```
=IF(B2=0,0,SUMIFS($C$2:$C2,$A$2:$A2,A2,$B$2:$B2,">0"))
```

[image]